# ffmpeg mov_text subtitle too small when converting mkv to mp4

Tags: video, ffmpeg, mp4, subtitles, mkv

I want to *remux* a mkv file into mp4.
I used the following command.

```
ffmpeg -i "input.mkv" -c:v copy -c:a copy -map 0:0 -map 0:1 -map 0:2 -map 0:3 -c:s mov_text "output.mp4"
```

#### Problem: The subtitles in the `output.mp4` file are way too small.

Also, the subtitles of the mp4 file are unaffected when I try to make them bigger from vlc preferences.
I can turn them on/off but I think they are somewhat hardcoded.
I had to rencode subtitles while remuxing as otherwise it was showing error.
Also, I'm using the latest version of mmpeg.

#### `input.mkv` :

[image]

#### `output.mp4` :

[image]

`input.mkv` has the following streams,codecs :

[image]

**I searched a lot, but couldn't find a way to make `mov_text` subtitles bigger. How can I make them bigger?**

Or Please suggest any other way to retain the subtitles while remuxing from mkv to mp4.

Answer (score 0):

I consider subtitle text rendering is part of the player feature. If you are using VLC, may this link, https://wiki.videolan.org/VLC_HowTo/Adjust_subtitle_font_settings/, help?

I had tried on a mkv to mp4 video, before
[image]

After, I changed the VLC subtitle font size to larger, exited the program and replayed it again, i got
[image]

Comment: I already tried to change font size, appearance from vlc preferences, as I mentioned in the post. But it did not have any affect on the subtitiles.

Comment: i updated my answer with screen-capture

Comment: Every other text becomes large except the subtitles.[ScreenShot](https://i.imgur.com/37DfEx0.png)  , Also you can notice that the subtitles are not hardcoded. Still their size is unaffected by changes in vlc preferences.